# How to sum days to a NSDate

Tags: ios, swift

How I could sum days to a DATE of type NSDate in order to create multiple events from this DATE?

This is my code that control the iOS calendar:

```
import UIKit  import EventKit    class ViewController: UIViewController {


    }
    @IBOutlet weak var needPermissionView: UIView!

    let eventStore = EKEventStore()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        checkCalendarAuthorizationStatus()
        // 1
        //let eventStore : EKEventStore = EKEventStore()

        /*
        // 2
        switch EKEventStore.authorizationStatusForEntityType(EKEntityType.Event) {
        case .Authorized:
            print("Authorized")
       //     insertEvent(eventStore)
        case .Denied:
            print("Access denied")
        case .NotDetermined:
            break
        // 3
        default:
            print("Case Default")
        } //        insertEvent(eventStore)   */
    }




    func checkCalendarAuthorizationStatus() {
        let status = EKEventStore.authorizationStatusForEntityType(EKEntityType.Event)

        switch (status) {
        case EKAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined:
            // This happens on first-run
            requestAccessToCalendar()
        case EKAuthorizationStatus.Authorized:
            // Things are in line with being able to show the calendars in the table view
            loadCalendars()
           // refreshTableView()
        case EKAuthorizationStatus.Restricted, EKAuthorizationStatus.Denied:
            // We need to help them give us permission
            needPermissionView.fadeIn()
        }
    }

    func requestAccessToCalendar() {

        eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(EKEntityType.Event, completion: {
            (accessGranted: Bool, error: NSError?) in

            if accessGranted == true {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    self.loadCalendars()  //                   self.loadCalendars()  //                   self.refreshTableView()
                })
            } else {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    self.needPermissionView.fadeIn()
                })
            }
        })
    }



    func insertEvent(store: EKEventStore) {
        // 1
        let calendars = store.calendarsForEntityType(EKEntityType.Event)


        for calendar in calendars {
            // 2
            if calendar.title == "ioscreator" {
                // 3
                let startDate = NSDate()
                // 2 hours
                let endDate = startDate.dateByAddingTimeInterval(2 * 60 * 60)

                // 4
                // Create Event
                let event = EKEvent(eventStore: store)
                event.calendar = calendar

                event.title = "New Meeting"
                event.startDate = startDate
                event.endDate = endDate

                // 5
                // Save Event in Calendar
                var error: NSError?
                let result: Bool
                do {

                    try store.saveEvent(event, span: .ThisEvent)
                    result = true
                } catch let error1 as NSError {
                    error = error1
                    result = false
                }

                if result == false {
                    if let theError = error {
                        print("An error occured \(theError)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func loadCalendars() {
        insertEvent(eventStore)   //      self.calendars = eventStore.calendarsForEntityType(EKEntityType.Event)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edited

As @vadian suggests, I edited answer using calendar methods.

I suggest you to create your own NSDate extension, for instance:

```
public extension NSDate {

   func addDays(days: Int) -> NSDate {
       return self.addUnit(.Day, value: days)
   }
    
   func addHours(hours: Int) -> NSDate {
       return self.addUnit(.Hour, value: hours)
   }

   func addUnit(unit: NSCalendarUnit, value: Int) -> NSDate {
       let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
       return calendar.dateByAddingUnit(unit, value: value, toDate: self, options: .MatchNextTime)!
   }

}
```

In this way you can:

```
let date = NSDate()
let.addHours(10)
```

Comment: **Never** use literals like *86400* for date math. There are days with 23 and 25 hours when daylight saving time changes. `NSCalendar` has powerful methods to do that more reliably.

Comment: For example `dateByAddingUnit:value:toDate:options:`

Comment: Ok @vadian, I edited answer as you suggest. Also, thank you for point me to this solution!

Comment: You're right. I'm reading NSCalendarOptions documentation and trying to understand differences between different options!

Comment: Last remove all square brackets `[]`. They are not needed for a single parameter.

Comment: How I could create an date array and insert dates?

Comment: Ask a new question